# How can i except specific lines with sed?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, sed

I have this command to run git log and refresh a list of file:

```
sed -E 's|(.*): .*|echo \1: $(git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct" \1)|e' app/config/file.yml
```

My problem is this command refresh every line in file.yml but i have a prefix which i don't want to refresh. The prefix is web/compile/*

I tried to do with this but unfortunately delete eveything whitout /web/compile prefix.

```
sed -i.bkp '/web\/compiled\/*/!e' -E 's|(.*): .*|echo \1: $(git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct" \1)|e' app/config/file.yml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First of all, you should know that **using sed to modify a yaml file is risky**. (I saw you retain the leading stuff till *the last* `:` to avoid interfering the indentations, but it is not safe )
- using sed, you can match a pattern by `/pattern/{action}`, here you just fill the `pattern` part with your "prefix" path. However, double-check your "prefix", if there are leading spaces(indent), you may want to have `\s*/web/com....`
- similar to your `s|pat|rep_or_cmd|e`, you can use another separator for the pattern matching, which we talked about in the last item if your pattern contains slash. so `\@^\s*/web/compile@` will be easier to read
- come to solution. You have two different ways to do what you want:

  ```
  sed '\@^\s*/web/compile@n; s|your s cmd....|' file
  ```

OR

```
    sed '\@^\s*/web/compile@!s|your s cmd....|' file
```

### Note

In your question, the prefix you wrote sometimes `web/compile` sometimes `/web/compile`, you should write the right one in the sed command and test.

Comment: Okay, it looks liek good. One another little question. What about if i want to use one another eexcept? eg.:  web/compile/*    and */fonts/xy

Comment: @TDex you mean "or" ? regex has `|`

Comment: No. Something like this: \@^\s*web/compile@!s|\@^\s*fonts/Akrobat@!s|(.*): .*|echo... So web/compile/* AND /fonts/Akrobat

Comment: @TDex No, you mean **OR** `/prefixA or prefixB/n; s|yourCmd...` "or" here can be `|` or `\|` it depends on if the `-r` option is there. If you say `AND`, that means one line matches both paths, I don't think you really meant it.